# 'Could not apply an Indexer because the property chain is empty' error when validating an IEnumerable model with FluentValidation?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, fluentvalidation

I am trying to validate an IEnumerable model using FluentValidation, but I keep getting the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Could not apply an Indexer because the property chain is empty.
   at FluentValidation.Internal.PropertyChain.AddIndexer(Object indexer)
   at FluentValidation.Internal.CollectionPropertyRule`1.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<InvokePropertyValidatorAsync>b__0(TProperty v, Int32 count)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectIterator[TSource,TResult](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`3 selector)+MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.IterateImpl(IEnumerator`1 enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func`2 breakCondition)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
```

I have an Item class with a Name and Price property, and an ItemListValidator class that validates IEnumerable. Here is the code:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

public class ItemValidator : AbstractValidator<Item>
{
    public ItemValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(item => item.Name)
            .NotEmpty()
            .MaximumLength(50);
        
        RuleFor(item => item.Price)
            .GreaterThan(0);
    }
}

public class ItemListValidator : AbstractValidator<IEnumerable<Item>>
{
    public ItemListValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(items => items)
            .NotNull()
            .Must(items => items.Any())
            .WithMessage("The list must contain at least one item");
        
        RuleForEach(items => items)
            .SetValidator(new ItemValidator());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RuleForEach(items => items)
            .SetValidator(new ItemValidator()).WithName("nameWhatYouGuess");
```

Comment: Please add some text explaining this solution. A code-only solution is typically not helpful.